# A hyperplane in a $k$-algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let there exist a nonsingular bilinear pairing $B:R×R→k$, where $R$ is a finite dimensional algebra over a field $k$, such that $B(xy,z)=B(x,yz)$ for all $x,y,z$ in $R$. Why the set $\{z∈R∶B(1,z)=0\}$ is a hyperplane in the $k$-space $R$?

I know the definition of a hyperplane of $R$ as a linear subspace of dimension one less than that of $R$, but could not link this notion to the above set. Can any one help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$z\mapsto B(1,z)$ is a nonzero linear transformation of $R$ to $k$, and you're discussing its kernel. What does the rank-nullity theorem say?

Comment: Since $B$ is nonsingular, the rank of this linear transformation (which is less than or equal to $1$) could not be $0$. So, it equals 1.OK!